# Is this expected apt-cache behavior?

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cache

Shouldn't the number of pkgnames match "Total Package names?"

```
ericm@saxman:~$ apt-cache pkgnames | sort | wc -l  
54411  
ericm@saxman:~$ apt-cache stats  
Total package names: 70821 (1,416 k)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is expected behaviour, at least going by the manpage description. It looks like `apt-cache pkgnames` does not include:

- missing packages (those named in the dependencies, conflicts, etc. of other packages, but which don't exist in the repository)
- packages which are exclusively for something other than the default architecture
- pure virtual packages
- and possibly other things.

Comment: I read the manpage as  apt-cache pkgnames *does* include those.  Which why I'm surprised it's off by being lower.  I believe the totals _should_ match, but, if off, I would expect higher.

Comment: @R5w2ii33HhLSq I agree, that's why I don't think it is expected behaviour

Comment: I guess I'm not curious enough to go read the code. ;)